# passing values form views to controller in mvc .net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

for view:-

here op is my selected value from html dropdown & e is value of a button click..
**`i just want to pass both two values to my controller`** from where i can put those in my sql query. how i can pass those two variable in my @UrlAction so i can get those in mycontroller

```
  function details()

{                                                                                            
 var op; 
var e = document.getElementById("test").Value;

$("mydropdown option").each(function (i) {

  var op = $(this).attr('selected').val();
})

window.open('@UrlAction("UserLayerView", "home", new {layertype = e, layername= op })')
}
```

for controller:-

```
public ActionResult UserLyerView(DataTable as dt, String layertype, String layername)
{
string query = "select column name from" + layertype + "Where name =" +layername; 
}
```

Comment: danger will robinson! never ever concatenate user input into a sql query- I could completely pwn your database server *just from the query string* - look into SQL parameters; now; what is the question here? does the `UrlAction` work? (and: shouldn't that be `Url.Action(...)`?) does it give the right result? what happens when the window.open fires? basically: in what way do your expectation and reality differ?

Comment: no UrlAction is not working

Comment: and what does "is not working" mean here? is it failing with a compilation error? is it giving the wrong result? is it throwing an exception at runtime? Did you try `Url.Action(...)` instead of `UrlAction(...)`?

Comment: I so want to search for layer `name and 1=0; drop table users; --`

Comment: Side note: Concatenating query string is not a good thing since it induces SQL injection attempt - use parameterized query instead. Also you can't use client-side variable concatenation inside `Url.Action` - it should be using query string like this: `window.open('@Url.Action("UserLayerView", "Home")' + '?layertype=' + e + '&layername=' + op)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing client-side and server-side code. The `e` and `op` variables are client-side javascript; `Url.Action` is server-side razor code. You cannot use client-side variables in a server-side operation, because *they don't exist yet* (and when they do: `Url.Action` will make no sense). So; you'll have to build the url manually and dynamically via concatenation. You *could* also set inputs on a hidden form (perhaps `action="get"`) and submit that.